# Does Freedman's disk embedding theorem extend to infinitely many immersed disks?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 4-manifolds

I'm referring to a statement of the disk embedding theorem on P17 in a book of Behrens-Kalmar-Kim-Powell-Ray, *the Disk Embedding Theorem*. See below. There are some new formulations, e.g., Theorem 1.2 in https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.03961 but still regarding the finite collection of disks or surfaces.

[image]

So my question is already in the title

> Q1. Does Freedman's disk embedding theorem extend to a countable union of immersed disks?

Q1 is my main question but it might be too hard to give a clear answer at this moment. A more sensible question might be the following

> Q2. There are various obstructions to disks being embedded in 4-manifolds, e.g., Kervaire-Milnor, van Kampen etc. Is there an obstruction well-defined for a countable collection of immersed disks with pairwise disjoint embedded boundaries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general working with infinite collections of maps is harder. As far as I know, the main result in this direction is the "disc deployment lemma" of Frank Quinn. Roughly, it says that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that an infinite collection of immersed discs, with dual spheres, controlled by $\delta$, can be replaced by an embedded collection, controlled by $\epsilon$. This is a very powerful result, which Quinn used to prove fundamental results about 4-manifolds, such as topological transversality and that noncompact 4-manifolds are smoothable.

The original source for this result is Frank Quinn's paper titled "Ends of Maps III: dimensions 4 and 5". published in the Journal of Differential Geometry. It is a challenging paper to read. You might also consider looking at the treatment by Edwards in "The solution of the 4-dimensional annulus conjecture (after Frank Quinn)", published in the conference proceedings of a conference called "Four-manifold theory (Durham, N.H., 1982) (the official citation is: Four-manifold theory (Durham, N.H., 1982), 211–264, Contemp. Math., 35, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 1984). In the book by Freedman and Quinn, the relevant theorem is on page 90.